# Rendering admin static files - DJANGO

Tags: python, django, macos, django-admin

I'm new to Django and the css for the admin area are not rendered. first, i created an app with admin module loaded and thats what i did :

configured the setting.py by changing the debug mode to false and added the database credential. then:

```
manage.py syncdb

Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

-

```
manage.py collectstatic

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings.

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Copying '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/base.css'
Copying '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/changelists.css'
Copying '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/dashboard.css'
Copying '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/forms.css'
Copying '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/ie.css'
Copying '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/login.css'
Copying '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/rtl.css'
```

(...)

what i get when i start the server

```
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[09/Feb/2013 13:57:53] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3270
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 153, in get_response
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 153, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 228, in handle_uncaught_exception
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 228, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)
```

the home page gives a "A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.", i can access the site.com/admin/ but without css. The project folder looks like this :

```
--project
----manage.py
----admin
-------css
-------img
-------js
----project
-------setting.py
-------urls.py
-------wsgi.py
-------__init__.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly if you're running the development server (with `python manage.py runserver`), then you should have your `DEBUG` set to true. Also it looks like your `STATIC_ROOT` setting hasn't been set (or is set to the root of your project - this isn't what you want when you come to run your application in production).

In your settings.py file you need to make sure you have `django.contrib.staticfiles` included in the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. Then make sure you've got STATIC_URL defined (I think it should default to `/static/`). Assuming you're using django 1.4 on django's dev server, everything should just work without needing to run `collectstatic`.

Have a look at the docs on [serving static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/). It's worth noting that the process for serving static files is different when you do it on a production server.